# Why QueryResponse has no nextPageToken attribute

Tags: c#, google-api, google-bigquery

When I execute my `QueryRequest` object, I get a `totalRows` of around 110,000 while the response rows are around 38,000. So I guess I am receiving only the first page.

```
QueryResponse response = j.Query(qr, project).Execute();
```

In the above code `j` is a `JobsResource` and `qr` is a `QueryRequest` object.

`QueryResponse` has a `pageToken` property that is the returned page's token. But how can I retrieve other pages in the query? I don't find any `nextPageToken` property.

When I execute the `List()` method of my `JobsResource` object, it has a `nextPageToken` property but not in the `Query()` method above.

```
JobList jobList = j.List(Globals.ProjectId).Execute();
```

**UPDATE:** 
I am reading the docs for [Google BigQuery's related page for query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query?hl=en). When I look at the description for `JobRefrence`, it says:

> Reference to the Job that was created to run the query. This field
>   will be present even if the original request timed out, in which case
>   GetQueryResults can be used to read the results once the query has
>   completed. Since this API only returns the first page of results,
>   subsequent pages can be fetched via the same mechanism
>   (GetQueryResults).

So once I receive my response above I run GetQueryResults() for my job.

```
GetQueryResultsResponse r = j.GetQueryResults(projectId, response.JobReference.JobId).Execute();
```

But this gives me the same results as my response. How can I get the next page? What does Google mean by *"Same Mechanism"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `QueryResponse`, you can access `JobsReference`, where you'll find the `JobId` and `ProjectId` (though you already have this one).

You can use these to call `GetQueryResults` on your `JobsResrouce` to generate a new request for the next page:

```
j.GetQueryResults(response.JobsReference.ProjectId,
                  response.JobsReference.JobId).Execute();
```

Comment: Yes I was looking at the same thing. But how can the statement you have written produce the next page?

Comment: I mean the above statement returns a `GetQueryResultsResponse`. This object has a pageToken property, too. But how to get e.g. page #2?

Comment: There's an `Execute()` call in there. Pay attention :-)

Comment: Does `Execute()` automatically result the next page?

Comment: It does according to the docs (see [PageToken](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Bigquery_1_1v2_1_1JobsResource_1_1GetQueryResultsRequest.html#ac0e5a4ecb696df4f3b632fe9cb05c59f))

Comment: I don't think it does. I have checked some values on both results set and they are the same values. And it makes sense because once we are only checking for the results of the same job that we ran. There is no mentioning of getting a next page or anything like that. That's why I am wondering how to retrieve the second page.

Comment: But ***there is*** mentioning of getting the next page, in the link from my previous comment: "*Page token, returned by a previous call, **to request the next page of results***"

Comment: I can't reproduce this ATM, but perhaps you need to fill the `PageToken` value of the generated request before executing... If so, please let me know and I'll correct the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The query / getQueryResults methods are used to push some of the waiting for job completion into the server. Clients may see faster notification of job complete when using this mechanism, and will receive the first page of the query results in that response, avoiding the need for one additional round trip to fetch the data.

The general mechanism for using these apis, in pseudo code, is:

```
response = query(...)
while (!response.jobComplete) {
  response = getQueryResults(response.jobReference);
}
moreData = false
do {
  // consume response.rows
  moreData = response.pageToken != null
  if (moreData) {
    response = getQueryResults(response.jobReference, response.pageToken)
  }
} while (moreData)
```

Note that some type safe languages will be more difficult to code this, as the first response in that do loop may be a `QueryResponse` or a `GetQueryResults` type, depending on whether the query job finished within the initial timeout on the `query(`) call, or whether it finished within the `while (!response.jobComplete)` polling loop.